# how to make mat-menu which should not overlap on the trigger

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a long list in mat menu which should not overlap on the trigger

[here, I am not able to see trigger if the list is more its overlapping on trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqSxa.png)

https://stackblitz.com/angular/egdpolqbbgp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.html

```
<!-- #docregion mat-menu-trigger-for -->
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<!-- #enddocregion mat-menu-trigger-for -->
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>

  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>

  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Put the menu inside the button element and add the ` [overlapTrigger]="false"` to the `mat-menu` per @Havald. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549264/angular-material-menu-position

Answer (score 0):

The matMenu provides an input to handle whether or not the menu should overlap the trigger ([docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api)):

setting `overlapTrigger = false` should do the trick:

```
<mat-menu [overlapTrigger]="false"></mat-menu>
```

Comment: i have included  <mat-menu [overlapTrigger]="false"></mat-menu> but still i can see overlapping,

Comment: @Halvald you have any example what you explain here?